# How do I improve my question skills?

Tags: discussion, voting, asking-questions

I seem to be experiencing a rash of deeply polarized voters. If they were voting for or against me personally, I could understand. But if these votes are cast for my content I would like to find resources to improve them.

[image: Polarized voting]

Is this polarization normal or do I need lessons?

Note roughly 20% of my posts look like this.

Comment: I don’t have time for a long answer to this but I will say this: **listen to the comments and take the feedback on board.** I’ve seen a lot of the time you seem to argue back to comments rather than listening to what they have to say until it is repeated several times by several users.

Comment: Often that's because I'm right and the comments are non-productive or missing. I'm better than 60% on reopening questions with trivial changes. To the question, is polarized voting normal? Yes. Voting against the author would explain this best.

Comment: I encourage you to re-read your last message and find what’s wrong with it. When you’ve done that you will have your answer.

Comment: Why doesn't anyone like what I write? ... :°

Comment: You also have no evidence users are voting against you yourself rather than the posts. Don’t assume wrong doing where there might not be any.

Comment: Can you like some of the questions? Poking through your posted list to try to find the  polarised ones is a bit frustrating.

Answer (score 5):

After a bit of poking around, my view is your questions are polarizing or controversial because they are ones where the reason probably comes after the solution. By that I mean a plot is written that involves a situation that you ask 'Why' about and most likely no one asked that at the time, but may have filled in the blanks later.

This [Talos 4](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220862/why-didnt-starfleet-destroy-talos-iv) question is a prime example. They didn't destroy it because someone decided to use Talos 4 again in a plot. The answer is decent, but reaching.

The [Nacelles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/221025/why-are-starfleet-vessels-designed-with-nacelles-so-far-away-from-the-hull) question is another example. The (really good) answer cites a source from 1975 when the Enterprise was on screen a decade earlier. The ship looks like that because that was the chosen design, the radiation reason for it is back filled when someone feels like it.

Sometimes these questions are saved by a great answer. I tend to downvoted stuff like this because the real answer is either 'retcon' or 'it looks cool' or 'There is no story without it', though I haven't downvoted these because I don't often go into TOS questions.

Comment: [This](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/221221/why-do-spaceships-in-star-wars-have-wings) fits into the same theory. It'll be interesting to see if it suffers the same controversial fate.

Answer (score -3):

There are many different users on this site with many different opinions. A certain amount of polarization is to be expected. Here are some of my posts, for instance:

[image: Screenshots showing voting scores of my posts]

If we look at Meta it is even more pronounced:

[image: Screenshots showing voting scores of my Meta posts]

Enjoy the ride!

Comment: Yourself and the OP of this meta question appear to be outliers when it comes to splitting the votes. You’ve worded this like it is normal which it certainly isn’t.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot You may be right – I don't keep much track of other users' posts' voting breakdown.

Comment: I don’t but what you and the OP are showing here isn’t normal. I can tell you that much.

Comment: If this is a consequence of poor wording this would be the place to guide improvement efforts, yes? If it's a consequence of bias, well it's systemic.

Comment: You lost me their @VogonPoet. Are you talking about bias in favour of the posts, against the posts or (somehow) both?

Comment: after a curosry look at some of the questions with high downvotes indicated above by you (Alex), one consistency between Alex and Vogon is the questions are *quite* verbose. Perhaps these are getting downvoted because they are just a slog to read and could use improvement? I know I've commented a few times on questions that I felt could use pruning. Have probably downvoted some that just seem rambling and undirected, but certainly have never explictly targeted a user. That would just be sadly pettty

Comment: @NKcampbell - SFF users seem to have problems with questions that aren't just verbose, but where the question contains large chunks of only-tangentially-relevant info that would sit better as a self-answer (or has been added seemingly just to demonstrate the asker's cleverness)

Comment: @Valorum I’d be curious to see an example of what you consider “large chunks of only-tangentially-relevant info”.

Comment: @Alex - If you go look at his current question you can see it happening live in technicolor